# Keras-rlでfit()におけるweightsの利用・再学習について

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Keras-rl を使用してDQNの学習を行なっているのですが、
`1,000steps` 学習して、`save_weights(fname)` で保存した重みのファイルが存在するときに、

```
    load_weights(fname)
    fit(xxx, nb_steps=3000)
    save_weights(fname, overwrite=True)
```

これを実行した場合、学習は `1,000steps` の続きから始まり、合計 `4,000steps` 学習したことになりますか？
また、保存される重みは、 `3,000steps` 学習した結果ですか？ `4,000steps` 学習した結果になりますか？

学習 `steps` 数が足りないと感じたときに、今ある重みファイルを使用し、続きから学習させたいと考えています。
もしどなたか分かる方がおりましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

[これ](https://keras.io/ja/getting-started/faq/#keras-model)を読むと、`save_weights()`/`load_weights()`はモデルの重みのみのセーブ/ロードと書いてありますね。`save()`/`load()`で「学習を終えた時点から正確に学習を再開できます」と書いてあります。

> model.save(filepath)を使うことで，単一のHDF5ファイルにKerasのモデルを保存できます．このHDF5ファイルは以下を含みます．
>
> ```
> 再構築可能なモデルの構造
> モデルの重み
> 学習時の設定 (loss，optimizer)
> optimizerの状態．これにより，学習を終えた時点から正確に学習を再開できます
> ```